# What are the torsion coefficients of $\Bbb Z_{30}\oplus \Bbb Z_{18}\oplus\Bbb Z_{75}?$

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, free-abelian-group

What are the torsion coefficients of $$\Bbb Z_{30}\oplus \Bbb Z_{18}\oplus\Bbb Z_{75}?$$

I know that $\mathbb{Z}_n \oplus \mathbb{Z}_m \cong \mathbb{Z}_{n\times m} $ iff $\gcd(n,m)=1$, I've tried to compute them, but I couldn't. I ask for help.

Comment: What do you mean by "torsion coefficient"?

Comment: More generally, $(\mathbb{Z} / m \mathbb{Z}) \oplus (\mathbb{Z} / n \mathbb{Z}) \simeq (\mathbb{Z} / \gcd(m,n) \mathbb{Z}) \oplus (\mathbb{Z} / \operatorname{lcm}(m,n) \mathbb{Z})$.  You could apply that repeatedly until you get a sequence where each term divides the next, as desired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using only what you know, we have
$$(30,18,75) \to (2,3,5,2,9,3,25) \to (3,30,450).$$.

Comment: Thank you a lot!!